# Arabic strings in visual studio code editor

Tags: editor, text-editor

Anyone knows how i can set visual studio code editor ( Microsoft editor ) to be able to display Arabic strings in the code.
as the image shows , whenever i write Arabic strings it is displayed as squares.

[image: image of the problem]

I tried to take a look at the settings file and the character set was utf8! i was working with brackets and it works fine with Arabic strings ?

Answer (score 2):

You may add a font that support Arabic script, e.g. Courier New, into `"editor.fontFamily"` option.